# Cannot make a derived instance of monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers, deriving

I have the following `newtype`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Wrap m a = Wrap {runWrap :: m a}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadTrans)
```

I'm trying to derive `MonadTrans` automatically, but I get the following error:

```
• Can't make a derived instance of ‘MonadTrans Wrap’
    (even with cunning GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving):
    cannot eta-reduce the representation type enough
• In the newtype declaration for ‘Wrap’
```

However, writing the trivial instance for `MonadTrans` works just fine:

```
instance MonadTrans Wrap where
  lift = Wrap
```

What is the reason for such an error message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` uses the underlying instance for a class for the implementation of the class for the `newtype`. However, in this case that doesn't make any sense, because `m` isn't of the right kind to even be an instance of `MonadTrans` (recall that `m :: * -> *`, but `MonadTrans` wants `(* -> *) -> * -> *`).

Comment: What do you mean by "underlying instance for a class" in this context?

Comment: Is there a way to derive trivial instances for `MonadTrans`?

Comment: Almost a year later [it seems I keep on hitting the same wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579216/doing-dependency-injection-using-monad-stacks).